# Flutter - How to execute a function only once in build method?

Tags: flutter, dart, rendering

I am trying to get a function to run (render a widget) only once. This is my main build function of the screen. You may ignore most of the code, just see the commented line towards the bottom.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  workoutId = box.get('workoutId');
  
  final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
  exerciseName = arguments["exerciseName"];
  exerciseId = arguments["exerciseId"];
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: kBlack,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      title: Text(
        exerciseName,
        style: const TextStyle(
            color: kAppTextColor, fontSize: kAppButtonTextFontSize),
      ),
    ),
    body: Container(

      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                child: BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 15, sigmaY: 15),
                  child: Container(

                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        _buildInputHeaderRowWidget(),
                        _buildInputRowWidget(),
                        _buildDataTable(),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                          child: Divider(
                            height: 10,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            thickness: 3,
                          ),
                        ),
                        //_buildDataTableForCompletedExercises(),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            child: (workoutId != null) 
                                ? _buildDataTableForCompletedExercises() ///THIS NEEDS TO RUN ONLY ONCE
                                : const Text(
                                    'Workout ID is null',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: kAppButtonTextFontSize),
                                  ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

How do you achieve this? Do I need to set a flag or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what you want to do is basically "cache" the result of the function you show, here is what I figure you could do:

First declare a nullable widget, you can call it whatever you want:

```
Widget? _completedExercises;
```

then either:

1. assign it to be the function on init state:

```
void initState() {
  _completedExercises = _buildDataTableForCompletedExercises();
  super.initState();
}
```

and then use the widget on the build method:

```
...
child: (workoutId != null) 
  ? _completedExercises!
  : const Text(
...
```

or 2. make the function itself cache the value:

```
Widget _buildDataTableForCompletedExercises() {
  if (_completedExercises == null) {
    _completedExercises = Container(); // here put whatever your function used to be.
  }
  return _completedExercises!;
}
```

The idea is that the first time the function runs, it will assign the value of `_completedExercises` and then all subsequent runs will just return the previous value.

Comment: Thanks but I did not understand the second method. What does the comment mean?

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain because I don't know how the original function looks like, but the idea is to make `_completedExercises` to be the same as what you would have originally returned, so if for example you were to return a button, you can instead just assign `_completedExercises` to be that same button, hope that's a bit more clear?

Comment: I tried the first method,  I get an error

" The following ArgumentError was thrown building Builder:
Invalid argument(s)

The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
lib\main.dart:25"

Comment: that's weird, would you mind showing the code or a screenshot of the lines you got the error on? Just so I get a better picture of what might be happening

Comment: The second approach would work but I realized _completedExercises needs to be a void function. So where you have put a container, it has to be a void function. How do go about it now?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand, what do you mean `_completedExercises` has to be a void function? It should be a widget shouldn't it?

Comment: So basically the _buildDataTableForCompletedExercises() function calls another function inside it and that is the one that needs to be called only once. I guess it can be achieved with a boolean flag..?

Comment: Yes, If you don't have anything to return, you could just set a boolean value